# Process scheduling and core allocation on big.LITTLE CPUs

Tags: cpu, android, arm, scheduling, cpu-frequency

Recent ARM chips, like the Qualcomm Snapdragon 810, seem to be using a hybrid architecture called "big.LITTLE" with cores of different architectures and speeds combined into one CPU.

On a Linux (or other unixoid) system, how does the kernel distribute processes to those cores, and how does the userland representation of this architecture look? Does the niceness of processes play a role in core allocation?

I was curious to check this in the AOSP code, but could not find the relevant information. Hence, pointers are very much appreciated, too.

Comment: Start by reading the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE). It doesn't get into the details of how it's done in Linux, but it explains that different SoC families use different strategies (corollary: look in SoC-specific code, not just in generic ARM code).